# Sequence of Video Indexer indexing outputs of videos having same duration with other factors being same

Tags: azure, azure-video-indexer

1. Does VideoIndexer finish indexing videos in sequence if video duration is 1min each and are sent after a consecutive gap of 1min?
2. Will it affect the speed of indexing when multiple instances of indexing are in progress?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation offers some guidance to scale Video Indexer at scale.
https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-video-indexer/considerations-when-use-at-scale

1. Jobs are put on a queue and handled in parallel. Scaling is done by Video Indexer backend.
2. Jobs are picked up as fast as possible and adding multiple jobs won't affect individual jobs. There can be a time for scaling additional resources if large quantities of jobs are added. It's best to add all jobs at the same time within the API limits to avoid the risk of fighting up/down scale logic.

Comment: Do you mean to say that sequencing of video indexer responses isn't guaranteed even if jobs are submitted after a delay?

Comment: Yes, it's not guaranteed, it will most likely be the case in the design you proposed. Can you elaborate why is this important to you?